# avoid converting " to &quote;

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am creating connectionstring at runtime but issue is double quote symbol (") automatically converted into "e;. How can I solve this?

Below is my code:-

```
 System.Configuration.Configuration Config1 = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

                ConnectionStringsSection conSetting = (ConnectionStringsSection)Config1.GetSection("connectionStrings");

                string providerName = @"providerName=" + "\"System.Data.EntityClient\"";
                string conString = @"metadata=res://*/OWordpress.csdl|res://*/OWordpress.ssdl|res://*/OWordpress.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=" + "\"data source=" + host + ";initial catalog=" + dbName + ";user id=" + userId + ";password=" + password + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework\"\'" + providerName;
                ConnectionStringSettings StringSettings = new ConnectionStringSettings("OWordpressContainer", conString);
                conSetting.ConnectionStrings.Remove(StringSettings);
                conSetting.ConnectionStrings.Add(StringSettings);
                Config1.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

After creating Connectionstring it looks like below:-

```
<add name="OWordpressContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/OWordpress.csdl|res://*/OWordpress.ssdl|res://*/OWordpress.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.0.46;initial catalog=test4;user id=sa;password=Admin123#;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;&quot;&quot;providerName=&quot;System.Data.EntityClient&quot;" />
```

But I need connectionstring as below:-

```
<add name="OWordpressContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/OWordpress.csdl|res://*/OWordpress.ssdl|res://*/OWordpress.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.0.46;initial catalog=OWpress;user id=sa;password=Admin123#;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: does that cause an error? I don't think it should.

Comment: "The connection string 'OWordpressContainer' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute.\""

Comment: Would using a single quote `'` instead of double quotes `"` help?

Comment: you still have a **&quot** in your desired `connectionstring`.

Comment: looks like you are missing the semicolon as a delimiter in your first example. It looks like this: App=EntityFramework&quot;&quot;&quot;providerName=&quot;System.Data.EntityClient&quot;. If you replace all "&quot;" (the semicolon here is part of the double quote) with ", you will see that you don't have a delimiter after the "App" setting in your connectionString. And you have unnecessary double quotes between app and providerName.

Comment: Looking at the example `providerName` is a separate attribute, which is not part of connection string. So, you cant add it in this fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [following overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19xhe2by%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `ConnectionStringSettings` class, which takes a providerName.
You could use it like that:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration Config1 = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
ConnectionStringsSection conSetting = (ConnectionStringsSection)Config1.GetSection("connectionStrings");
string providerName = "System.Data.EntityClient";
string conString = @"metadata=res://*/OWordpress.csdl|res://*/OWordpress.ssdl|res://*/OWordpress.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=" + "\"data source=" + host + ";initial catalog=" + dbName + ";user id=" + userId + ";password=" + password + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework\"\'";
ConnectionStringSettings StringSettings = new ConnectionStringSettings("OWordpressContainer", conString, providerName);
conSetting.ConnectionStrings.Remove(StringSettings);
conSetting.ConnectionStrings.Add(StringSettings);
Config1.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```